# How to create an attendance table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, php-carbon

I'm trying to create a table that shows the attendance of clients in a gym for a week.
In the rows of the table i have the client's name and on the column's i have the day's of the week (without Sunday). If the client has made a check-in on that day it should just display a check mark if not then just leave it empty
What I'm trying to do:

| names\days | Mon | Tue | wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client1 | Y | X | Y | Y | Y | X |
| client2 | Y | Y | X | Y | X | Y |
| client3 | Y | Y | X | Y | Y | Y |

But when i test it for every cell it shows an X
This is my code so far:

```
public function weekCheckIn(){
        $startWeek = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(Carbon::MONDAY);
        $endWeek = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek(Carbon::SATURDAY);
        

        $clientWeek = Client::with(['client_scans' => function($query) use ($startWeek, $endWeek){$query->whereBetween('user_check_in',[$startWeek,$endWeek]);}])->get();
        
        return $clientWeek;
    }
```

And in the blade file:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <th></th>
                    @for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
                            <th>{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(Carbon\Carbon::MONDAY)->addDays($i)->format('D') }}</th>
                        @endfor
                        </tr>
                            @foreach ($weekStatus as $client)
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>{{ $client->name }}</b> {{ $client->surname }}</td>
                                    @for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
                                        <td>
                                            @if (in_array(Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(Carbon\Carbon::MONDAY)->addDays($i)->format('Y-m-d'),
                                                    $client->client_scans->pluck('user_check_in')->toArray()))
                                                Y
                                            @else
                                                X
                                            @endif
                                    </td>
                            @endfor
                    </tr>
            </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

using dump() on the parameters of in_array() it returns:
[image]

"The records are created using Eloquent: Factories"

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in your blade file, because it's really hard to understand

Comment: I get all the check_ins a client has made in a week and then try to check if user_check_in(timestamp) matches days of the week ex: 2023-01-16(Monday) $client1->client_scans->client_check_in() '2023-01-16 18:40:55'

Comment: dump your first parameter of `in_array()`, then dump the second parameter and check if you really do have that needle in your haystack. It might be related to format()

Comment: yes you were right  it was related to the time format 
Thank you for yout help